# How to load a keras model file to OpenCV code?

Tags: python, opencv, classification, video-capture, h5py

I've created a traffic sign classification model. I need to use it in OpenCV for Video traffic sign detection.
How can I do that using a `.h5` file

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Without any code it is difficult to solve your problem.

Comment: if you show question without details then you can get answer also without details: `try harder`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In openCV you can read weights with

```
cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe
cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorFlow
cv2.dnn.readNetFromTorch
cv2.dnn.readhTorchBlob
```

Because you can not read with opencv without manipulations and you need:

1. You can read frames with OpenCV and put the frames to run in Keras
2. Or you can convert keras model to tensorflow model and run with Opencv cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorFlow